# Why are these divs behaving like this?

Tags: css

Okay, so i've been working on a little site for personal use. However, all the divs up until now on this one page have been behaving perfectly.
[Here is how they are behaving.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzx7M.jpg)
The only CSS which is involved with these specific div "cards" is as below:

```
#card1, #card2,
#card3, #card4,
#card5, #card6 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  margin: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
  width: 826px; -- i adjust this based on how much of the page these need to cover
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
}

#main{
 display: table;
 table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Main is the div container that all of these "Cards" are contained within. Cards 4-6 are the ones mis-behaving and for whatever reason wrapping around the middle as seen in the image. The divs simply are containers with content - in this case a header with a subheading and an image.

JsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/pt88b5be/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Pretty sure it's a simple problem but you really need to add your html for us to help you. Just think, if someone asked you the same thing, how would solve it without seeing the actual markup

Comment: Added @Huangism

Comment: I saw it however the fiddle is working fine, I don't see the issue in it

Comment: The issue is in the screenshot, it seems to be only prevalent in 21:9 ratio, 16:9 it works. Basically, the cards should be in rows of three - however, as seen in the screenshot they are simply wrapping to the right and then to the left, skipping the middle two spots where they are suposed to be sat as opposed to being in two rows of three divs. If you zoom the page out in fiddle, you will notice it.

Answer (score 0):

If the "cards" are not floating as expected I would look at the content of each, to me seems like the image is different in size which makes the #card2 (471.19px instead of 471.14px as the others) to have different height dimensions so not floating one after each other.

Try to add a fixed height (using height or max-height) dimension for your cards and this problem will be fixed.

```
#card1, #card2,
#card3, #card4,
#card5, #card6 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  margin: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
  width: 826px; -- i adjust this based on how much of the page these need to cover
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 471px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use flexbox for `#main` and change the id's for the cards to a class. Note that flexbox is responsive by nature. Hope this helps.

```css
html,
body,
#main {
  width: 100%;
}

#main {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
width: calc(100% / 3);
}

.card img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="card">
    <h4>Image desc</h4>
    <h2><b>Info</b></h2>
    <img src="https://m2bvzg.by.files.1drv.com/y4moS5ebacGDCsml4yYlLX5RtoloimHGfjy11BQA1loEgY9iFvWZJXEEop90z1Usub4Ft-rNDLLXj8FJMNPWOMqzwIzlcQiF46WRQyScQTflu4M-a9XhjTGWu4Ce_oOuFyfKZTH-jt7tdKLW6wl1j_JeT6c1Qhh6mK5ZgHBPIwZMumJz4lU1nfB_C8Cy-BeHNNUPeNwdJpfzlrWOBwFLNQXxw?width=660&height=278&cropmode=none"/>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h4>Image desc</h4>
    <h2><b>Info</b></h2>
    <img src="https://owakqw.by.files.1drv.com/y4mQlgdD9bjBiQRL00Iq31kAXH2DKk7FZt-PWTtjEqT2Hqt7UVKIJxC_PxgtBHSOSo6ZypSW2MXOgQbSf_obmwpVCtzCmSVZdfSak7qzkwTSryL-RuD3KH1WOVB0BVZ3uR23tzh18_T5mbwyCVLXW_u594vzz5zgE0L5Y4fWGJXgRpgtYKG2VJQTPfklu-bmb18zGQGFUTar6l8hIoxnofClQ?width=2560&height=1080&cropmode=none"/>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h4>Image desc</h4>
    <h2><b>Info</b></h2>
    <img src="https://m2bvzg.by.files.1drv.com/y4moS5ebacGDCsml4yYlLX5RtoloimHGfjy11BQA1loEgY9iFvWZJXEEop90z1Usub4Ft-rNDLLXj8FJMNPWOMqzwIzlcQiF46WRQyScQTflu4M-a9XhjTGWu4Ce_oOuFyfKZTH-jt7tdKLW6wl1j_JeT6c1Qhh6mK5ZgHBPIwZMumJz4lU1nfB_C8Cy-BeHNNUPeNwdJpfzlrWOBwFLNQXxw?width=660&height=278&cropmode=none"/>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h4>Image desc</h4>
    <h2><b>Info</b></h2>
    <img src="https://m2bvzg.by.files.1drv.com/y4moS5ebacGDCsml4yYlLX5RtoloimHGfjy11BQA1loEgY9iFvWZJXEEop90z1Usub4Ft-rNDLLXj8FJMNPWOMqzwIzlcQiF46WRQyScQTflu4M-a9XhjTGWu4Ce_oOuFyfKZTH-jt7tdKLW6wl1j_JeT6c1Qhh6mK5ZgHBPIwZMumJz4lU1nfB_C8Cy-BeHNNUPeNwdJpfzlrWOBwFLNQXxw?width=660&height=278&cropmode=none"/>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h4>Image desc</h4>
    <h2><b>Info</b></h2>
    <img src="https://m2bvzg.by.files.1drv.com/y4moS5ebacGDCsml4yYlLX5RtoloimHGfjy11BQA1loEgY9iFvWZJXEEop90z1Usub4Ft-rNDLLXj8FJMNPWOMqzwIzlcQiF46WRQyScQTflu4M-a9XhjTGWu4Ce_oOuFyfKZTH-jt7tdKLW6wl1j_JeT6c1Qhh6mK5ZgHBPIwZMumJz4lU1nfB_C8Cy-BeHNNUPeNwdJpfzlrWOBwFLNQXxw?width=660&height=278&cropmode=none"/>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h4>Image desc</h4>
    <h2><b>Info</b></h2>
    <img src="https://m2bvzg.by.files.1drv.com/y4moS5ebacGDCsml4yYlLX5RtoloimHGfjy11BQA1loEgY9iFvWZJXEEop90z1Usub4Ft-rNDLLXj8FJMNPWOMqzwIzlcQiF46WRQyScQTflu4M-a9XhjTGWu4Ce_oOuFyfKZTH-jt7tdKLW6wl1j_JeT6c1Qhh6mK5ZgHBPIwZMumJz4lU1nfB_C8Cy-BeHNNUPeNwdJpfzlrWOBwFLNQXxw?width=660&height=278&cropmode=none"/>
  </div>
</div>
```